# how to use constant field values defined in predefined classes

Tags: java

My question is how to use constant  field values defined in predefined classes like I am practicing on the events program, and currently on action event, I have understand
the action listener part but when I go to action event part , I don't know how to use the static field constant, only I am able to use methods of the that classes, it will be more helpful if a simple example is given by you (simple not complex)

Elaboration:

I want to know how to use the ALT_MASK, ACTION_FIRST, ACTION_LAST constant
Also please show me how to create events of my own

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine you have class:

```
public Class ConstantsHere {
    public static final int INTEGER_CONSTANT = 5;
}
```

Then, you want to use it in another class, and you write code like this:

```
//some code
if (myValue < ConstantsHere.INTEGER_CONSTANT) {
    //do something
}
```

As mentioned in commens, Java `Enum` may be a good choice for this task:

```
public enum Action {
    ALT_MASK, ACTION_FIRST, ACTION_LAST;
}
```

Usage:

```
//some code
if (myValue == Action.ACTION_LAST) {
    //do something
}
```

To make things clear, `Enum` should be used in case when some variable may take limited number of values. For example, human gender can be only male or female (please do not take this as offensive for transsexuals, statement used only for explanation purposes), so it might be a good idea to use `Enum` for that instead of constants `0` and `1` (or `M` and `F`), just because we can put other number (or constant) there and break the logic.

Comment: In modern java there's [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) data type

Comment: @user3159253 sure there is, but the question was "how to use constants". Anyway, I will add the information, thanks.

Comment: thank u for ur support please tell me how I can create my own action event and register it with some source say like button

Comment: @Kaushal That really depends on frameworks/API/whatever you're using.

Comment: I am using eclipse kelper and the api 1.6

Comment: @Kaushal unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with that tools :(

Answer (score 0):

Using enums example.

```
public enum UserStatus {
    PENDING("P"), ACTIVE("A"), INACTIVE("I"), DELETED("D");

    private String statusCode;

    private UserStatus(String s) {
        statusCode = s;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

}

public void method(UserStatus status) {

        System.out.println(status.getStatusCode());

    }

}
```

Comment: thank u for ur support please tell me how I can create my own action event and register it with some source say like button

Comment: in what library you would like to implement action event?

Comment: sorry I am unable to understand the term library, just at beginner level. I have learn that when we want something to be happen when we pressed a button than for that purpose we have to implement actionlistner from the event class and register it with the button(source), but if I want to create my own event than how to do that

Comment: so, that might be hard for you when you don't know which library you use, I can't help you if you don't know what lib you use.